# Move an object on its own with Pygame

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a circle move from the middle of the screen to the top, and then back to the middle, and so on, using Pygame.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

gameOver = False
speed = 5
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 20

class Screen:
    largeur = 600
    hauteur = 600
    demiLargeur = int(largeur/2)
    demiHauteur = int(hauteur/2)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen.largeur, Screen.hauteur))

class Couleurs:
    bleu  = (000,000,255)
    noir  = (000,000,000)

class Cercle:
    diametre = 50
    epaisseur = 5
    posTop = [Screen.demiLargeur, Screen.demiHauteur-2*diametre]

class CirclePos:
    top   = [Cercle.posTop[0],Cercle.posTop[1]] 

circleListTop = [CirclePos.top]


class DrawCircles:
    def top (circleListTop):
        for CirclePos.top in circleListTop:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, Couleurs.bleu, (CirclePos.top[0],CirclePos.top[1]),Cercle.diametre,Cercle.epaisseur)

class UpdateCirclesPositions:
    def top(circleListTop):
        for idx,CirclePos.top in enumerate(circleListTop):
            if CirclePos.top[1] > Cercle.diametre :
                CirclePos.top[1] -= speed
            else:
                circleListTop.pop(idx)

while not gameOver:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(Couleurs.noir)
    clock.tick(fps)

    DrawCircles.top(circleListTop)
    UpdateCirclesPositions.top(circleListTop)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I have this code so far, the idea being to make it move up, make it desappear, and then create another list to move circles from top to middle. I feel it's a bad idea.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: as for me you have too many classes. Circle should keep position and have method  to move it and method to draw it. There is no need to create class to move circle and another class to draw it..

Comment: when circle is at the top then change speed - `speed = -speed`. When it comes bact to the middle then change speed again - `speed = -speed`. BTW: Sometimes it can be useful to have variable which keeps information in which direction it moves - up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me you have too much classes. In class Circle you should have its properties and methods `update` and `draw`.

When circle is at the top then it should change speed - `speed = -speed`. The same when it is in the middle. This way it may move all time. But it may need variable `direction` to check if it already changed direction because it can be in place where it may change speed all time (in every move).

```
import pygame

# --- constans ---

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 20
SPEED = 5

# --- classes ---

class Colors:
    blue  = (000, 000, 255)
    black = (000, 000, 000)
    red   = (255, 000, 000)

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, x, y, size=50, thick=5, color=Colors.blue, speed=SPEED):

        self.size = size
        self.thick = thick
        self.color = color

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 2*size, 2*size)
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y
        if speed >= 0:
            self.direction = 'up'
        else:
            self.direction = 'down'

        self.speed = speed

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.rect.center, self.size, self.thick)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed

        if self.rect.top <= 0 and self.direction == 'up':
            self.direction = 'down'
            self.speed = -self.speed

        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.centery and self.direction == 'down':
            self.direction = 'up'
            self.speed = -self.speed

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

circles = [
    Circle(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.centery),
    Circle(screen_rect.centerx, 0, speed=-SPEED, color=Colors.red)
]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_over = False

while not game_over:

    # --- events ----

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

    # --- updates --- (without draws)    

    for item in circles:
        item.update()

    # --- draws --- (without updates)

    screen.fill(Colors.black)

    for item in circles:
        item.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit() # close window
```